# Want autocomplete widget to filter on SharePoint List data pull

Tags: jquery, select, autocomplete, spservices

I have a list of about 150 or so  list entries.  I'm using a custom jquery ui combobox for selection from it. I'm trying to match up, at least a little of the list entry, if not all of the entry, to an item of data pulled form a SharePoint List.  I'm using SPServices to pull the data from the SharePoint List for the user:

```
function getUserAccountInfo() {

    var user = {};
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
        async: false,
        accountName: accountNameObject,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {

            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").each(function() {
                var propertyName = $(this).find("Name").text();
                var propertyValue = $(this).find("Value").text();
                user[propertyName] = propertyValue;             
            });
        }
    });

    return(user);
}
```

with the following code to attempt to fill in the value to the Autocomplete Select:

```
function fillNewUserInfo(user) {

    $("#userID").val(user.AccountName);
    $("#userInfoLastName").val(user.LastName);
    $("#userInfoFirstName").val(user.FirstName);
    $("#userInfoMiddleInitial").val(user.MiddleInitial);

    //fill in current date
    var fullDate = new Date();
    //convert month to 2 digits
    var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
    var currentDate =  twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getDate()+ "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
    $("#inputDate").val(currentDate);

    $("#userTitle").val(user.Title);
    $("#userInfoDepartment").val(user.Department);
}
```

The line:

```
    $("#userTitle").val(user.Title);
```

Is the one that would trigger the select list autocomplete, yet it doesn't seem to be doing anything?  I just have a blank entry on the list after running the code, but all the entries for the autocomplete list are there when you focus on the field.

Any thoughts?

Oh, a little data:

If a "CONTR" is pulled for the user.Title, it should match up to:

"CONTR / CONTR / Contractor" from the select list.

Comment: OK, I tried this:

`$("#userInfoGradeRank").autocomplete('select', user.Title);`

yet I get a

`cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'select'`

Comment: OK.  HOw about a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkz24o3w/) to play with